# How to return length of string in xargs (special characters)

Tags: linux, string, bash, char, xargs

```
#!/bin/bash

a=ača

echo ${#a}                                 #returns 3
echo $a | xargs -rL1 sh -c 'echo ${#0}';   #returns 4
```

In first echo it gives me right length of string. What should I do, to return right length of string in second echo? (I want length 3 in both cases)

In my program I have a lot of lines, which I have to edit, that's why I use xargs.

Comment: I get 3 for both. On my system (Fedora 23) `bash --version` gives `GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)`

Comment: lucky you, I'm using linux mint

Comment: @amdn Your `/bin/sh` is properly linked to bash and not a more posix strict non unicode aware shell like dash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not `xargs`.  The problem is `sh`.  If you want the correct (unicode) length, you need to use a shell that supports unicode.  Observe:

```
$ echo $a | xargs -rL1 sh -c 'echo ${#0}'
4
$ echo $a | xargs -rL1 bash -c 'echo ${#0}'
3
```

On debian-like systems, the default shell, `/bin/sh`, is actually `dash` which does not understand unicode.  As shown above, simply replacing `sh` with `bash` solves the problem.